# Transferencia en mysql con python

Tags: mysql, python, sql

¿como transfiero dinero a otro registro sumándole su valor actual?

```
sql = "UPDATE clientes SET balance = balance + %s WHERE IBAN = %"
self.iban = int(input("Ingrese el IBAN del destinatario: "))

val =  (self.quanty, self.iban)

cursor.execute(sql, val)

validation = cursor.fetchone()

if validation:
    print("¡Dinero enviado correctamente!")

else:
    print("IBAN invalido")
    break
#error "Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement")
#mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were                 #used in the SQL statement
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo hago así...

sql = "update clientes set balance = balance + " + str(self.quanty) + " where iban = " + str(self.iban)

y luego

cursor.execute(sql, "")

val y %s solo lo uso en los insert